# Rails association "has_many :through" in the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: Company and Business.
The Business belongs to two Companies (supplier and client). So I have wrote:

Business model:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, :class_name => 'Company'
  belongs_to :supplier, :class_name => 'Company'
end
```

Company model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businesses
  has_many :companies, through: :businesses
end
```

But I can't do @company.companies to access the companies that are related to a company through his businesses. How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried  `has_many :clients, through: :businesses`

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work, because the Business don't have a company_id. @AbePetrillo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an additional table BusinessRelationship that has a property such as "relationship_type" which would be either "client" or "supplier", or indeed a reference to another table of RelationshipTypes. But that's adding lots of tables to a simple data model, so to start with you might just want to keep things simple:

In Company

```
has_many :businesses_as_client, class_name: "Business", inverse_of: :client, foreign_key: :client_id, dependent: :destroy
has_many :businesses_as_supplier, class_name: "Business", inverse_of: :supplier, foreign_key: :supplier_id, dependent: :destroy
```

In Business

```
def companies
  (self.businesses_as_client + self.businesses_as_supplier).collect(&:company)
end
```

This might not be very efficient, so you could do something like:

```
def companies
  Company.where(:id => (self.businesses_as_client.collect(&:supplier_id) + self.businesses_as_supplier.collect(&:client_id)))
end
```

Or something of that order. Extending on this, you could even try this in Company:

```
has_many :companies_as_client, through: :businesses_as_client
has_many :companies_as_supplier, through: businesses_as_supplier

def companies
  companies_as_client + companies_as_supplier
end
```

That could be a long shot though!